# do_action from within a class does not seem to work

Tags: plugin-development, actions

I have a class within a plugin which is loaded via the below code:

```
<?php

add_action(
    'plugins_loaded',
    array ( 'Company_Store_Locator', 'init' )
);

class Company_Store_Locator{

public static function init() {
    $class = __CLASS__;
    new $class;
}
```

And I have a constructor with a number of `add_actions` which are within my construct - these all work fine, however when I try and `do_action` for one of these nothing appears to happen. I am trying to return an admin notice only if certain criteria within a function occurs. The function is running as expected but nothing happens for `do_action` as I need to pass a variable to the admin notice function I cannot use add action here.

```
public function __construct() {

    add_action( 'admin_notices', array($this,'sample_admin_notice__success'));
```

Inside my `public function create_tables()` function:

```
$message = 'Tables created successfully';

do_action( 'sample_admin_notice__success', $message);
```

How would I get the do action to run in this scenario?

Comment: Have you tried if other actions work? Few days ago I've seen some question here and OP had some problems with admin notices as well, so maybe the problems lies in notices and not in actions?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż I can make an `add_action` work for notices, so if I want to just do one on plugin init, but not the `do_action` where I run something specific and need to pass the variable.

Comment: If not done already, setting debug on might give you more clues.
Add this to your wp-config.php file `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); `

Make sure your `sample_admin_notice__success` is publicly accessible and the php file with the class is included.

Comment: @Gert it is accessible, if I switch to a `add_action` it works fine but fires the notice at the wrong point (init) and I cannot pass the message variable.